# Google custom search (CSE) API in Python to ask 24,000 queries with multiple query keywords in text file

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search

Firstly, I will be eternally grateful for anyone who can provide me with any help with this. I am trying to query the Google custom search API for the whole web in a relatively complex way with Python. I have successfully queried the API for one phrase queries and I understand how to change the domain, language etc.

But what I want to do is search for;

PepsiCo scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.de** domain

Then

PepsiCo scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.co.uk** domain

PepsiCo scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.com** domain

And so on covering all 30 country domains

Then second search term, ten pages of results and the thirty different country domains.

Samsung scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.de** domain

Then

Samsung scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.co.uk**    domain

Samsung scandal,  returning 10 pages of results, for **google.com** domain

And so on covering all 30 country domains.

I have 80 search phrases I want to run through this loop, but I am not sure how to achieve this. I am quite new to Python, I understand some of the concepts but I have spectacularly failed in actually implementing them into a script that works for this use case. Again, any help at all will be much appreciated.

Search Terms - 80
Google Country Domains - 30
Pages of Results per query - 10
Total Queries - 24,000

I am aware I will have to pay to run this many queries of the API. It is a one off search. Thanks again! Below is the basic code, I haven't added in any of the nonsense code I have been experimenting with it would just complicate the issue!

```
import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():

    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
        developerKey="key")

    res = service.cse().list(

        q='Pepsico + Scandal',

        cx='search engine ID',

        cr="countryUK",

        lr="lang_en"

    ).execute()

pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```